# How to run node js server on Win CE ARM embedded device?

Tags: node.js, arm, windows-ce

I have a device that has an ARM processor and runs Win CE OS.

Now I have got a requirement to implement a node js server inside the device.

The same requirement was implemented on another ARM device that was running Linux

Since node is compiled for Linux they were able to run a node js server inside the device.

But there is no Win CE compatible version of node available

Is that not done yet or am i missing something?

I read about Microsoft chakracore, but I didnot understand much.

Does anybody know how to run node on Win CE running devices.

Any kind of leads/help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Windows CE provides an implementation of the Win32 API that is someway compatible with the full-Win32 version implemented on Windows desktop operating systems.
It also provides C/C++ libraries but, as you know, evil is in the details and those implementations can be considered a subset of those you have on the desktop and missing a single function or feature can force you to re-implement a huge amount of code to work around the limitation.
Windows CE is also meant to run on resource-limited devices with a limited amount of RAM and processing power and, honestly, node.js does not seem to exactly target this kind of platforms. 
First I would like to understand if the requirement makes sense and why there is a need to mix a small real-time OS like CE with a huge interpreted and resource-hungry monster like nodejs.

Comment: We have an Embedded web server in the device we are using. We now want to remove the EWS and run Node inside the device so that we can serve requests much faster. Its a decision made by the boss above my boss and I just have to convince them whether it is feasible or not. From what I read, node js is a good alternative to PHP which is indeed resource consuming and hence the reason to move to Node. So are you saying that node js built for Win 32 machines can indeed run on Win CE?

Comment: @ShaikSyedAli Given that neither Node, Google V8, or even ChakraCore offer Windows CE support - and thus the idea that Node would somehow be "faster" can only have been pulled out of thin air - I'd call the requirement poorly-researched and rate it somewhere between "unreasonable" and "impossible". Whilst it might be _technically_ possible, realistically that would likely entail several man-years of porting effort coupled with no guarantee of success whatsoever - if a senior exec tells you to get SQL Server running on a Commodore 64, they might yet understand a ROI estimate to sway them ;)

Comment: No, there is no binary compatibility between CE and desktop Win32 and also source code compatibility is not complete, so porting a complex application may require a significant effort. And I agree about the fact that any performance improvement is pure theory. A theory that may require months of work to be tested.

Answer (score 1):

windows CE has not been updated in over 3 years it is unreasonable to expect node.js to work as is on top of CE. windows on arm however (used by windows phone, [windows Iot](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot), and the ill fated surface RT) can run this https://github.com/nodejs/node-chakracore. Windows on arm only accepts thumb2 instructions, so you won't be able to use regular node.js.

This is b\c v8 just in time compiler does not produce thumb2 instructions. more reading material here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2014/05/15/understanding-arm-assembly-part-2/